# How to keep update from several Git repositories as one application project?

Tags: git, github, git-pull

I'm developing a web application based on Laravel, jQuery, Bootstrap.

I Install Laravel using git clone and then use composer to install all dependencies.

I'm also learning using git.

If I wanted to keep my Laravel framework up to date while developing my own web application, I believe, I need to periodically pull the updates and merge into mine.

```
git pull laravel_remote_name
```

What-if I also want to keep my web application update to date for jQuery and Boostrap as well, please guide the right steps of doing this.

P.S. I also wonder how to organize the directory, without concert about the updates from github, I just place all .js (both jQuery and Bootstrap) in larave/public/js/ and .css (Bootstrap) in laravel/public/css, what about when I need to pull updates periodically how to organize the directory? Or using composer as require package is a solution for this?  If so, please explain me.

My system is Ubuntu 13.04

Answer (score 1):

While you develop an application you will need to freeze your libraries at some time. When you update the libraries of your application you can occur in some incompatibilities between releases.

For example a new `JQuery` release can deprecate some `API` you use in your application. Another example look, at the differences between `Twitter Bootstrap 2` and `Twitter Bootstrap 3`, you will need to manually manage all this updates.

Anyway, if you want to use this approach a solution would be using [git submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules). You can clone the git repos of your libraries (`JQuery`, `Bootstrap`) and keep them as a dependency for your application. In this way you can update the libraries pulling the updates whenever you want.

Regarding on how to manage the libraries inside your project you should follow your framework (`Laravel`) best practices.

Answer (score 1):

[git submodule](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules) is what you are looking for. But it doesn't update jQuery and bootstrap automatically. So, You have to specify commit SHA.

Anyway I think [Bower](http://bower.io/), client dependency manager,  is better for your case. because you don't develop jQuery and Bootstrap. so you can use released version.